# Draw icon on node's background using a graph theory / network library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, cytoscape.js, graph-visualization

I have data, which I want to represent as a graph in web browser. As far as I know - it's not a problem right now. However, I want to be able **dynamically draw the content** - an icon - for every node.

This picture/icon depends on the characteristic of the node and **cannot be stored as a preset image** - should be drawn while we are building a graph. I have already implemented drawing the icon in canvas (maybe it's not a good idea - we will see), but I'm not sure how to draw the icon on a node.  I tried out D3 and Cytoscape.js.

Simplified example of the icon could be a rectangle with a number of dots. This number and dots' positions are specified on the node.

How would I draw the image from the canvas onto a node's background, using D3 or Cytoscape.js etc?

Comment: Maybe [GoJS](http://gojs.net/latest/index.html) is a good fit ? Ironically, it's shown as a sidebar ad on your question :)

Comment: @Bigood, this one is very interesting! Do you have any experience with this? Maybe you know how scalable is it?

Comment: Absolutely not. As I mentioned, an ad for GoJS just popped out of the sidebar of stackoverflow along with your question !

Comment: @Bigood, lol! Great, at least I have some option as it looks like there is something similar indeed! However I will wait for the other answers. Maybe there will be more.

Comment: You want to draw a graph, and then on each "node" place a canvas and draw in the canvas?  Pretty sure `d3` can do this (it can do anything...) but your question is so vague, it's tough to help.  How about showing some code, some pictures, something, anything...

Comment: Maybe you want something like this sample: http://gojs.net/latest/samples/pipes.html, where each node is defined by a geometry path string, as you can see in the model data for each node.  Or maybe you want something like http://gojs.net/latest/samples/canvases.html where other libraries are drawing to a canvas which is shown in a GoJS node.

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods, yes, gojs and canvases were what I already looked at  after the first comment here. I think it is what I was looking for. However, I did prefer to wait and see what could be another options...

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more of a "how can I" rather than a "which lib should I use" question.  Maybe another moderator could take a look and see if this suffices for re-opening so others could answer too.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background images are natively supported in Cytoscape.js with many options.  For your usecase, it's easy:

(1) Export the image from your canvas to PNG or JPG: `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

(2) Set the `background-image` in the style for your node in Cytoscape.js with the data URI you got from the canvas: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image

You can do the same thing with SVG images, too.  You can even use libraries like [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) to build your SVG easily.  Again, just get the data URI for the SVG and specify it as the background image.

You can use [a mapper function](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/mappers) if you want to keep image generation organised in your stylesheet, too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try to do this upcoming days. It looks not hard indeed!